WP All Export: How to get taxonomy ID in Custom XML
I want to export CPT with custom taxonomy, but when I drag and drop {my_custom_tax} I got the name, but want the ID.
I tried
function my_tax_function() {        $cat_ID = get_query_var('my_taxonomy');          return $cat_ID; }
But it didn't work
